# Save float and int to file simultaneously in Python

Tags: python, file

I have a numpy array with a few columns, containing floats, and I want to add one more columns, containing only zeros and save this to file. For the program I need to use this file for, the last column should appear as 0 instead of 0.00000e+00. I tired this:

```
z = np.zeros(len(data[:,0])).astype(int)
new_data = np.column_stack((data,z))
np.savetxt("data_new.dat",new_data)
```

but it doesn't seem to work i.e. the zeros appear as floats. One more thing, how can I also specify the number of decimals that the floats should be saved with to the file? Thank you!

Comment: `np.column_stack((data,z))` is creating an array with `dtype` float. Arrays are *homogenous* containers of primitive numeric (or strutured) types.

Comment: What exactly is your use-case here? Any particular reason why you must use `np.savetxt`?

Comment: Can you add examples for values of `data` and `xi` to your code? I'm assuming `data_new` in the final line is supposed to be `new_data`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't have to use np.savetxt. That is what I used almost always before, but I can use anything here. I just need to save the data to file.

Comment: @Grismar Sorry data_new and new_data were meant to be the same. Here is an example for data: 3.53373e-04 4.13497e+05 1.96504e-04 -7.00163e+04

Comment: Then I suggest using [`numpy.savez`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez)

Comment: `np.savez` lets you save multiple arrays in a single binary file (`.npy` format). This takes care of preserving the dtypes, etc. If you just want to save a single array, use `numpy.save`. Avoid `numpy.savetxt` at all costs if you can. Using text to save your array  is fraught with problems, especially for floating point types

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I might have missunderstood your questions before. I do need to save the data in the .dat format, as this is what the program I will pass the file to needs. So, I would need to convert this .npy to .dat?

Comment: @BillKet what is ".dat"? `. Basically `np.savetxt` saves it as a csv... Is that what you need? Then you can't use `numpy.save` or `numpy.savez`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is the extension that I need for the file. When I call np.savetxt, I use "data_new.dat" It is basically a text file extension. What I meant earlier is that I don't need to save it using np.savetxt, but I need to save it as a text file (i.e. if using built-in python functions to save a file instead of numpy would do the job, I am fine with that). But I can't use a binary file.

Comment: @BillKet you realize, extensions are *arbitrary*, they don't enforce anything. You could save it as `data.foobar` and it is still a text file, basically a csv. The `.dat` extension is a convention used for "generic program data". It is basically meaningless. In any case,  if you want mixed-data types, use `pandas` and then it has a `to_csv` method. Alternatively, manually create the csv using the `csv` module

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I meant the code that I pass my file to requires as user input the name of the file and it adds .dat to it, so the file has to be .dat (no?). I will try the to_csv.

Comment: @BillKet my point is simply that `.dat` does not describe any format, it is basically a wastebasket extension for any program data. it can be binary, text, anything really. but if `np.savetxt` works then you pretty much are working with csv and cant use `np.save`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried to use to_csv, but the zero is still saved as a float i.e. 0.0. Is there anything else I need to do to save it as 0?

Comment: @BillKet how exactly are you creating the dataframe?